# Does Vega-Lite or Vega follow a Context-Free-Grammar? If so, is this grammar documented somewhere?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I am looking for a official grammar for Vega-Lite or Vega if available.
Ideally I am looking for something in [Extended Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) which could be compatible with [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark).

I tried looking at the docs, but couldn't find anything relevant.